# How to avoid null values while using lookuprows function, and keep looping through till we get the value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How to avoid null values while using Lookuprows function and keep looping through till we get the value

```
SET @rows = lookuprows("Products","Product_ID",@ProdID)
IF @rows > 0 THEN
    FOR @i = 1 to @rows DO
        SET @prod_Img = Field(Row(@rows,@i),"prod_img")
        IF (EMPTY(@prod_Img) or isnull(@prod_Img)) THEN
        Else
        EndIF
    next @i
EndIF
```

What I'm trying to implement is I want to loop through the rows returned till prod_img is not null.

Comment: Please elaborate on your needs and provide any relevant code you are currently using.  Otherwise this question is likely to be flagged to be closed.

Comment: what if lookuprows function returns 5 rows and the first 4 rows returns firstname as null and we'd need to loop through all the rows to get the 5th row value for the firstname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
%%[/* Modify to view AMPScript <div style="display:none"> */

var @rows, @rowcount, @row, @prod_img, @found

set @rows = lookuprows("products","product_id",@prodid)
set @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowcount > 0 then

    set @found = 0

    for @i = 1 to @rowcount do

        set @row = row(@rows,@i)
        set @prod_img = field(@row,"prod_img")

        if @found == 0 then

            if (not empty(@prod_img)) then
                set @found = 1
                output(concat("<br>",@prod_img))
            endif

        endif 

    next @i

else

    output(concat("<br>prodid not found"))

endif

/*</div>*/
]%%
```

Comment: hey Adam, how can I terminate the 'for loop' once I get a 'not null' value? so for suppose, there are 5 rows and I see a value in the second row, the loop should terminate and we should be able to capture the second-row value.

Comment: There's no "break" for AMPScript loops.  You can do it in SSJS, however.  If you need to do it in AMPScript, you'll need to set a flag. You'll still need to go through all of the rows.  Updated my answer above.